# Xcode Onesignal flutter integration

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, onesignal

I am creating an app with push notifications. I have follow this documentation https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup. Android works perfectly, IOS doesnt.

I try to build in xcode and it fails instantly. This is the NotificationsService.swift as required...

```
import UserNotifications

import OneSignalExtension

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var receivedRequest: UNNotificationRequest!
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.receivedRequest = request
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        self.bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            /* DEBUGGING: Uncomment the 2 lines below to check this extension is executing
                          Note, this extension only runs when mutable-content is set
                          Setting an attachment or action buttons automatically adds this */
            // print("Running NotificationServiceExtension")
            // bestAttemptContent.body = "[Modified] " + bestAttemptContent.body
            
            OneSignalExtension.didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: bestAttemptContent, withContentHandler: self.contentHandler)
        }
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            OneSignalExtension.serviceExtensionTimeWillExpireRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: self.bestAttemptContent)
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }  
}
```

I am getting an error at `import OneSignalExtension`. It says No such module. I'm not sure where I download the module. Please help!

Comment: Did you follow all the ios related steps detailed in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

place this in you podfile before post_install:

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end
```

and if you already have target `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` then just place this inside it `use_frameworks!, then do
pod deintegrate
pod install